# The most efficient way to query multiple tables with PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I finally found time to start learning PDO.  I am running my queries like this right now and was just wondering if there was a more efficient way I could be constructing these queries:

```
    //Do the database queries
    try{
        $checkInvites = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM invites WHERE email = '$email'");
        $checkInvites->execute();
        $inviteCheck = $checkInvites->rowCount();

        $checkQueue = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM inviteQueue WHERE email = '$email'");
        $checkQueue->execute();
        $queueCheck = $checkQueue->rowCount();

        $checkUsers = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
        $checkUsers->execute();
        $usersCheck = $checkUsers->rowCount();

        $getInvite = $db->prepare("SELECT code FROM invites WHERE email = '$email' LIMIT 0, 1");
        $getInvite->execute();
        $inviteCode = $getInvite->fetchColumn();
    }catch(PDOException $e) {
        $invError++;
        $errorMessage = "A Database error occured." . "\n";
    }
```

Comment: Use joins, inner, outer, cross depending on occasion and needs: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: For example: `Select I.ID IID, IQ.ID IQID, U.ID UID, I.Code ICode from invites I LEFT JOIN InviteQueue IQ on I.Email = IQ.Email LEFT JOIN users U on U.Email = I.Email Where I.Email = '$email' LIMIT 1`